# Facebook php sdk v.3.2.3 - event create suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-events

Over one month ago I created FB app for site, which was able to create user events. It uses FB PHP SDK v.3.2.3 with Graph API version 1.0:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => MYAPPID, 'secret' => MYAPPSECRET));
$facebook->api('/me/events', 'POST', array('name' => 'Your meeting', 'start_time' => '2014-06-20', 'location' => 'Cool place', 'privacy_type' => 'SECRET'));
```

About few days ago it suddenly stopped working - now facebook returns OAuthException: "An unknown error has occurred.". I use valid token (checked).

I checked FB Devs blog but nothing there about it (often case, sadly). Any clues?

Comment: Is your access token valid?

Comment: @Maerlyn : yes, my access token is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting an error as well, and it was due to 'privacy_type' => 'SECRET' and time formats ... It looks like sending privacy_type => SECRET will throw an OAuth error, but still actually create an event with the correct permissions.  ALSO, your dates need to be in ISO-8601 time format.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/

The reason privacy_type => SECRET will return an error, is that your app has permissions to create the event on the user's behalf, but once it is created, and set to private, the app doesn't have the necessary permissions to VIEW the event, and therefore can't return the event ID as a response.

I would try checking my time formats, and then just removing privacy_type and see what happens.

UPDATE: I also determined that you can set privacy_type to SECRET if you app also has user_events permissions.  Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks for thorough check, but unfortunately changing date format won't fix the issue. I also checked other privacy_type values and no luck there as well.

Comment: ...BUT: thanks to your suggestions I started to play with privacy_type field more and found the solution - which I'll publish in a minute.

Comment: @cromdev for events, 'privacy' is not a valid parameter...I can almost guarantee it is not setting your privacy to the setting that you like...if you are passing SECRET to 'privacy', your created events are likely still public. 'privacy_type' is correct, but your app needs create_events and user_events permissions to not return an oauth error on creation.

Comment: Brillant! you were right, it was missing "user_events" permission.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has [disabled the ability](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/events) to create Events for users via the API. The documentation says:

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

However, if you've using [1.0 of the Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/events), publishing is still allowed for a limited time only. But the `create_event` permissions has been removed.

Comment: Yes, I'm using version 1.0 of the Graph API. I'm aware of this limitation in v.2.0. The thing is now it's not working even in v.1.0., throwing just general exception.

Comment: It could be that Facebook (either knowingly or otherwise) have also removed the functionality from v1.0.

Comment: This should be selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems ridiculous, but changing

```
'privacy_type' => 'SECRET',
```

to

```
'privacy' => 'SECRET',
```

fixed the issue.

My guessing is that this month there was tiny and undocumented change in FB old API.

Big thanks @kevindeleon for directing me to check more on privacy settings.

Comment: As I said in my other comment, and I am just posting here in case you do accept your own answer as correct for others...be sure and check 'privacy' is actually working how you expect it... for events, 'privacy' is not a valid parameter (it just gets ignored)...I can almost guarantee it is not setting your privacy to the setting that you like...if you are passing SECRET to 'privacy', your created events are likely still public. 'privacy_type' is correct, but your app needs create_events and user_events permissions to not return an oauth error on creation of private (SECRET) events.

Comment: Correct, @kevindeleon answer awarded - kudos for him!